# How to deal with multi-tab forms( with or without jquery)

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a large page/form divided as tabs, now the requirement is such that, each tab should have a save button, which will submit the fields within that tab. And there should also be a global save button which saves the data from all tabs.

My idea of doing this was, making separate forms for each tab, and use jquery serialize to post them, but some of the forms have image upload and ckeditor fields which do not play well with jquery.

Any idea,about what would be the best way to solve this?

Comment: you mean something like `google docs forms`?

Comment: I don't exactly know much about google docs forms, but I don't think it is similar to my problem

Comment: Reading this question first thing comes in my mind is performance. Is this really going to help you even-if you find a solution ? What about combining all your data in a single form and do rest of the task in server side ? There are various ways of reducing number of parameters - one is: use comma-separated parameters.

Comment: What is the purpose of the local submit buttons? what is supposed to be happen on pressing them?

Answer (score 0):

A low impact appoarch is to leave your 3 forms as you have them. And then attach your a "form merge " to the submit element of the global form:

For the HTML:

```
<form id="form1"> ... </form>
<form id="form2"> ... </form>
<form id="global"></form>
```

JS:

```
$("#global").submit(function(e){
  var $ch1 = $("#form1").children();
  var $ch2 = $("#form2").children();

  $(this).append($ch1).append($ch2);
  //Let the form get submitted...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With Using jQuery, You can submit each form one by one

```
$("#globalsubmit").submit(function(e){

  //simply submit all the forms one by one
  $("#form1").submit();
  $("#form2").submit();

  return false;
});
```

Or Find all the form and submit at once

```
$("#globalsubmit").submit(function(e){

  $("form").each(function() { $(this).submit(); });

  return false;
});
```

---

Without jQuery. Here are the few steps you might want to follow.

1. Submit the form, do not process the data, but store in the session.
2. Collect all the data from all the form in the session and at the end Submit the data as a bulk.